# how to exec multiple commands from a single variable from a tcl file

Tags: linux, command, format, tcl

I am trying to make a custom MOTD header using a tcl file.  I've already been succuessful in adding the commands to the last line of the /etc/profile

```
cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/  | shuf -n1) $(whoami), $(fortune)
```

I want to add this into my existing MOTD but I do not know the proper syntax to exec multiple commands without the pipe break command.  As you can see below I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# * Variable
set cows [exec -- /usr/bin/whoami | /usr/games/fortune | cowsay]


# * Output

puts "$cows"
```

which outputs the fortune and cowsay fine but, I cannot seem to get the whoami command to exec up with the other commands.

```
\   ^__^
 \  (oo)\_______
    (__)\       )\/\
        ||----w |
        ||     ||
```

Any help regarding how multiple commands are executed from within the syntax of the tcl format would greatly be appreciated, thanks y'all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is fortune ignores stdin.

It looks like you are building a string to pass to cowsay.  Why not build the string in pieces using Tcl strings.  For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# * Variable
set cowsParam [exec /usr/bin/whoami]
append cowsParam ", " [exec /usr/games/fortune]
set cowImage [exec ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/  | shuf -n1]
set cows [exec cowsay -f $cowImage $cowsParam]


# * Output

puts "$cows"
```

Comment: Yes, iagreen thank you for the cowsParam string! =) but i think the real problem is getting the:

cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/  | shuf -n1)

to work inside a .tcl file.  i've been trying this as well, but can't seem to exec this

Comment: Not a problem at all, just follow the same pattern.  See the edits above.

Comment: -=congrats=- i was snagged up trying to do the $cowImage $cowsParam.  I was trying to figure out howto use the ls and | shuf -n1 within cowsay.  Many thanks friend!!!

Answer (score 4):

The answer by iagreen is of course correct and probably more maintainable, but to answer your subquestion: how to translate `$(some command)` into tcl:

In bash, the `$(...)` syntax executes the string captured by the parenthesis by evaluating it in another shell - a new instance of bash often referred to as a subshell.

In tcl, the `exec` command executes its arguments as a list of words to be evaluated in a subshell.

So, putting two and two together the correct translation of `$(...)` is `[exec ...]`.

Therefore, the direct translation of this:

```
cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/  | shuf -n1) $(whoami), $(fortune)
```

is this:

```
exec cowsay -f [exec ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | shuf -n1] \
               [exec whoami], [exec fortune]
```

Which is basically the same as the answer given by iagreen.